# what's the difference between using FLASK_ENV=development and app.run(debug=True)?

Tags: flask

I have always been puzzled about this. I usually use both while working with a flask application which sometimes I feel is redundant. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the debug flag, it's internal to the flask app. When you set an environmental variable, other extensions and related modules can use it too. For me, one such use case was when I used sentry.

Comment: Please can you explain a bit more, how can sentry use it? Like what if it does and what if it doesn't?

Comment: Sentry is for automatic error reporting. But that's not important. Many times, you will be using other related applications along with flask. Setting an environmental variable can serve as a commonplace to set the environment for the group of extensions for the flask and other programs that you might be using. In my case, I was using sentry. So instead of setting the environment in both of them, I can just set FLASK_ENV.

Comment: What do the extensions use it for is an entirely different question. One very general use case is we have different log file locations based on whether the environment is dev or prod.